# PIL Image opening turns white pixels into black pixels

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

When I open a FULLY WHITE file with pillow (`from PIL import Image`) and then obtain the color of all of the pixels, you SHOULD see something like `[255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255].....` but instead i only see `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].....`, code is as follows:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open("index.png", "r")
pixels = list(image.getdata())
print(pixels)
```

Comment: If it is possible, can you upload the image that is used in this code? It may consist of three channels and one of them may be dedicated for black and white pixel values

Comment: you can see it (And the code) here: https://repl.it/@Doomful/Image-close-to-ifier#main.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't convert white pixels values to black pixels. It somehow represents pixel values in different way. We can check whether it converts white pixel values to black pixels using RGB color domain. Code is shown below:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img = Image.open("index.png") # open colour image


imgRgb = img.convert('RGB')
pixels = list(imgRgb.getdata())
width, height = imgRgb.size
pixels = np.asarray([pixels[i * width:(i + 1) * width] for i in range(height)], dtype=int)
```